# message/rfc822 ignores utf-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, mime-types

I'm using JavaMail to convert incoming emails into attachments, and then attach them to another main email.

```
DataSource byteMail = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachedEmail.getMessageHtmlBody(), "message/rfc822; charset=utf-8");
DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(byteMail);
mailBodyPart.setDataHandler(dataHandler);
mailBodyPart.setFileName(attachedEmail.getMessageSubject());
```

By converting the incoming htmlMail to `MimeMessage`, I found that rfc822 doesn't response to utf-8. The german letters like `ä`, `ü`, etc are still garbled.

But rfc822 works well with "iso-8859-1"; "UTF-8" works good with other MIME types such as "text/html" and "www/mime".

Is it possible that rfc822 messages are not compatible with UTF-8? Or does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What type is `attachedEmail` exactly? And is its `getMessageHtmlBody()` returning the *entire* RFC822 email as a whole, or just the HTML portion of it? Because its name suggests the latter, in which case using `message/rfc822` would be wrong.

Comment: thanks for your reply! the attachedMail is not a special type, but just a local class. And unlike its name suggested, the ´getMessageHtmlBody()´ only returns a string. I´ve tested in debug model that `attachedMail.getMessageHtmlBody()` returns the value in utf-8 format. So I think the problem might occured when cutting the strings in ByteArrayDataSource.

Comment: I use the ´message/rfc822´ here because I want to cut the string into a email document. Maybe there is better solution for this? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: What *exactly* does `getMessageHtmlBody()` actually return? A complete RFC822 email, or just HTML by itself? This is important. And what does the final email look like when everything is done? If you are getting garbled characters, you are not setting everything up correctly. Can you show the complete email? RFC822 works fine with UTF-8 provided the email is using a compatible transfer encoding (8bit, quoted-printable, or base64).